# Arch Linux prevent lock when running specific application

Tags: arch-linux, power-management, suspend, i3-window-manager, zoom-meeting

I'm currently running **arch linux** with **i3**. To lock my device, I use **i3exit**. Furthermore I have **xfce4-power-manager** installed to manage sleep timers ect.

My problem is, that I can't figure out how to **prevent i3 from locking when I'm running a specific application**. For example, when I'm in a zoom-meeting, my screen would automatically shutoff followed by a system lock if I don't intervene.

I want to be able to add any given application as an exception, so that my system won't lock while at least on of those applications is running.

The only thing I found so far, was a bash script which disables the screensaver, but I don't like that solution. I'm looking for something cleaner. Here is the mentioned script: [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/267194/prevent-screensaver-when-flash-is-running-in-linux)